# exception in thread 'main' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, path, classpath, javac

When I try to execute the following program from DOS I get the results below..

The following program is in C:\Users\Apostolos\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java1\src\java1

```
package java1;

public class MyProgram{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Rome wasn’t burned in a day!");
  }
}
```

`javac MyProgram.java` 
works fine

But `java MyProgram` gives the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyProgram (wrong name
```

`: java1/MyProgram)`

`at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)`
`at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)`
`at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)`
`at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)`
 ................

Why this is happening??

My environment variables:

CLASSPATH: `.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin`

PATH: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin`

JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05`

I have seen similar problems here but i cannot find the solution to my problem.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `java java1.MyProgram`  !!!!Use the fully qualified name of the class .

Comment: run `java java1.MyProgram`

Comment: are you executing the java MyProgram from the directory containing the .class file

Comment: It gives me: `Could not find or load main class java1.MyProgram`

Comment: YOu can use path Entry like this %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 points you should keep in mind when using `java` tool:

1. Add the class to the classpath.
2. Use the fully qualified name of the class to be run.

Hence:

```
java -cp C:\Users\Apostolos\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java1\bin java1.MyProgram
```

assuming the following file exists after compilation:

```
C:\Users\Apostolos\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java1\bin\java1\MyProgram.class
```

---

For more info, see:

- [Mastering the Java CLASSPATH](http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html).
- ["Setting the class path" Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Comment: that worked!!! thank you very much! but one question: do i have to add every class to the classpath? It will get full of paths...

Comment: @gokutoriyama the path I've used should be enough if `bin` is the root folder for all the classes (assuming all of them are in packages). You need to include extra jars to the classpath if you use them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyProgram (wrong name
```

This exception is thrown when the JVM cannot finf your class at run time

```
From C:\Users\Apostolos\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java1\src 

execute " "java java1.MyProgram" –
```

Comment: how can I make JVM to find it during run time?

Comment: Can you check whether the MyProgram.class is generated in the directory after javac ?

Comment: Also whats the result when you execute the above program from NetBeans ??

Comment: From C:\Users\Apostolos\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java1\src execute " "java java1.MyProgram"

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

run command prompt as Administrator, and

```
cd C:\Users\Apostolos\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java1\src
```

then

```
javac java1/MyProgram.java
```

Then

```
java java1.MyProgram
```

This will work.